# React Native + Android (Java) + iOS (Swift)

Tags: javascript, android, swift, reactjs, react-native

I am new to the world of Hybrid Application.
I have read in a lot of place that React Native fails to prove its computational power as compared to Native approaches.

> Is it possible to write JavaScript code and when stuck, use the NATIVE CODE (JAVA AND SWIFT) in the same file to gain computational power.

*I just want to know that JavaScript+ Android+ Swift programming can be written simultaneously in the same app to make use of every feature altogether? Maybe for convenience or better productivity*

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No

Longer Answer: The closest thing React Native has to what you're talking about is implementing modules from native code, but you do that through JavaScript.

Quote from the Documentation on [How to Implement Native UI Components](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios):

> There are tons of native UI widgets out there ready to be used in the
>   latest apps - some of them are part of the platform, others are
>   available as third-party libraries, and still more might be in use in
>   your very own portfolio. React Native has several of the most critical
>   platform components already wrapped, like ScrollView and TextInput,
>   but not all of them, and certainly not ones you might have written
>   yourself for a previous app. Fortunately, it's quite easy to wrap up
>   these existing components for seamless integration with your React
>   Native application.

*Side Note: I have not used React Native before.*

Answer (score 0):

not in the same file, no, but in the same project. For some work, you will need to use third-party libraries (most of theme are writen with native langages), or create your own modules on android and ios and then use it for react native, those module will be writen on java for android and objective-c and swift ect for ios.

And for my little experience, react native is simple to use and you can build app very fast, mostly if you are used with javascript, but for my opinion, it's far from being a complete framework, it's not mature.